# What's wrong with my PHP Script? T_String issue

Tags: php

I'm just trying to get some data through a table in a specific row.

Here's my script.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","astralms");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$type = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['type']));
$username = htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']));

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM accounts
 WHERE name = '%s', $username);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    if($type == "nxcash") {
    echo $row['ACash'];
    } else if($type == "votepoints") {
    echo $row['vpoints'];
    } else if ($type == "gmlevel") {
    echo $row['gm'];
   }
  }
?>
```

However,
I get:

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'nxcash' (T_STRING) in
>   C:\wamp\www\accountdata.php on line 17.

when using it like `127.0.0.1/accountdata.php?username=tester&type=votepoints`

Thanks.

Comment: the syntax highlighting is a dead giveaway.

Comment: What did you tried? Why do not simple try to debug?

Comment: I think StackOverflow text highlighting script has already answered your question :)

Comment: Missing quote in `"SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = '%s', $username` put `"` after this.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `"`:

```
 WHERE name = '%s', $username);
//                ^-- there
```

Most IDEs will be able to pick out syntax error. I'd recommend investing some time getting familiar with a good one. There are free ones too.

Comment: glad to see it fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

You missed a closing double quote on your SQL query, after `WHERE name = '%s'`.

Answer (score 0):

Line 12/13.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = '%s', $username);
```

It is missing a quotation speechmark.

Comment: http://puu.sh/406Ai.png still error.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax highlighting right here on SO has highlighted your error:

This:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = '%s', $username);
```

Should be this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = '%s'", $username);
```

Notice the close quotes -------------------------------------------------------------------- here -----^

Comment: that's not where the closing quote goes. See the other answers.

Comment: Derp, you're right! More coffee needed... Answer updated, thanks :-)